# Cloudflare pages + custom domain, www CName record not working

Tags: cloudflare, cname, cloudflare-pages

I created a Cloudflare page sanket-sapate-github-io.pages.dev and connected it to sanketsapate.live
Both the links are working fine.

Now I want to add CName record www which redirects to any of two links.

After adding the record, visiting <www.sanketsapate.live> says Connection Timed out Error 522 even though both the previous url are working fine.

```
1 Created a cloudflare page named <sanket-sapate-github-io.pages.dev>.  
2 Connect the page to custom domain <sanketsapate.live>  
3 Created a CName record name=www target=@
```

[www.sanketsapate.live](http://www.sanketsapate.live) is not working.
Error code 522, Connection timed out

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the dns tag states: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding custom domain not enough, you need to do it a little bit different way, how described in that article: https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/configuration/custom-domains/#add-a-custom-domain

In a nutshell: you need to setup a Custom domain via Pages "Custom domains" configuration.

How documentation says:

- To ensure a custom domain is added successfully, you must go through the Add a custom domain process described above. Manually adding a custom CNAME record pointing to your Cloudflare Pages site - without first associating the domain (or subdomains) in the Cloudflare Pages dashboard - will result in your domain failing to resolve at the CNAME record address, and display a [522 error](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/cloudflare-errors/troubleshooting-cloudflare-5xx-errors/#error-522-connection-timed-out).